# Is there a way to solve $\int { \sin(ct) \over \cos(t) + \tan(t) }dt$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to solve the integral:

$$I=\int { \sin(ct) \over \cos(t) + \tan(t) }dt$$

where $c$ is a real constant. No matter which trigonometric identity I use to transform this integral, I can't get it to a solvable form. I even tried using the Feynman's technique, but that didn't help either. Any suggestion on how to solve this integral would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+sin%28kt%29%2F%28cost%2Btant%29+dt your integral is not expressable with currently defined functions it seems

Comment: I hoped it could be solved because Wolfram solves it if I input a specific value of $c$. For instance, it solves for 1, 2, and 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int { \sin(ct) \over \cos(t) + \tan(t) }dt=\int {\sin(t) \sin(ct) \over 1+\sin (t)-\sin ^2(t) }dt$$
If $c$ is an integer, use
$$ \sin(nt) = \sum_{k\text{ odd}} (-1)^\frac{k-1}{2} {n \choose k}\cos^{n-k} (t) \sin^k (t) $$ and using $x=\sin(t)$ , $\cos^2(t)=1-\sin^2(t)$, you will face simple integrals in $x$.

For example,
$$I_3=\int \frac{x^2 \left(4 x^2-3\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}
   \left(x^2-x-1\right)}\,dx$$
$$I_4=\int \frac{4 x^2 \sqrt{1-x^2} \left(2 x^2-1\right)}{x^2-x-1}\,dx$$

Remember that
$$x^2-x-1=\left(x-\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)$$ will help for partial fraction decomposition.